# Description for inlined image field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model#answer-537966) I'm wondering how to put a description text above the inline form  to notice the user admin.
I also read this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) but I'm always stuck!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for help_text but I can't exactly tell from your question where you are expecting the text to show up

Edit: with regards to the comment below.

If you use StackedInline instead of TabularInline, your help text will show up.

If you really want your help text to show up on TabularInline, copy the template from

django/contrib/auth/templates/edit_inline/tabular.html

add field.help_text somewhere around the  area to fit.

Comment: I thought about that, but I've multiple image fields... This is what I want : [link](http://profile.imageshack.us/user/sorcerousfox/)