# Can't Selecting Multiple fields in django admin

Tags: python, django, view

In My django admin form I have one Image Upload field and also It has been done for the preview support.Also I has clear option to clear that image in the object.If i need to select another image with also clicking the clear option "It does't do that" At a time it says only one option will be done.What I should have to do for the both operations?

Also What could do to have multiple ImageFields in django admin form?What are the ways to do it?[image]

Comment: Is there any easy way to have multiple image fields in django? atleast 5 needed also I need to be expanded dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use django inline model admin [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

earlier question on SO: [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model)