# Uploading a stack of images in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-uploads

I'm getting used to Django and I want to upload a stack of images via browser. The user must be able to upload the whole stack from one field to store the images in the database keeping the order. I think I'm looking for something like:

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
    MultiImageField(upload_to = "/stack_name/").
```

And i have the models like this:

```
class Stack(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Images(models.Model):
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    stack = models.ForeignKey(Stack)
    originalImg = models.ImageField(upload_to='/stacks/')
```

I'm pretty lost with this, Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple images per Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model)

Comment: I'm not looking for uploading from the admin page. I would like to upload from the main view from one field.