# Django: How to go about loading multiple images from multiple objects on same render in html

Tags: python, html, django

I have been searching and came across this ([Multiple images per Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model)) which explains how to get all the images for a specific object but how would I load multiple images for a list of 2,000+ objects - I know I could loop and grab all the objects from each image but then how would I display the correct images with the correct objects in the html?

While writing this, I was wondering if this is a good use for template_tags but I am extremely new to them.

Working with these basic cut down models as an example.

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    auction_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Listing(models.Model):
    auction_id = models.ForeignKey(Auction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ListingImage(models.Model):
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField()

view example to run off of, expecting anything up to thousands of items returned.  
listings = Listing.objects.filter(time_ending__gte=datetime.now()).order_by('time_starting')
```

so with that example view above how would I go about grabbing each image for each of those listings and then more of an issue was finding the way to display those in html in loops or in any order or specifically chosen.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to list all the images (you can include more info as per your choice).

Within the same app:

**views.py**

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import ListingImage

class ImageListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'ImageView.html'
    model =  ListingImage

    def get_context_data(self):
        image_list = ListingImage.objects.all()
        context = {'image_list': image_list}
        return context
```

**templates/ImageView.html**

```html
...
{% for image in image_list %}
    <li> {{ image.image }} </li>
{% endfor %}
...
```

You also have to define the URL in **urls.py** for that page. This is the minimum application. You can customize it as you want.

**Edit**
What ended up being the big solve that I did not understand, I was able to access the images from the object they were linked to. So in the end it was simply by having a view with the context being `Listings = Listing.objects.all()` and then by using this loop

```
{% for listing in listings %}  
  {% for image in listing.images.all %}  
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" />   
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not sure what the second loop would be if I did not have related_name on the image model, `listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')`

Comment: Yeah, that is perfect for dumping out all the images, though I am trying for the images of each object. IE: Object A, object A's image/images, object B, object B's images ect...  random number of images per object, possible to be none.

Comment: So if you want to list images for a particular listing in different URLs, then, in your urls.py, `'listing/<int:pk>/images/', ImageListView.as_view(), name='image_list'`, and modify the query, `image_list = Listing.objects.all()`, and in your template, use `{% for image in image_list.image %}`. The link which after clicking will lead to respective listing's image should be like: `<a href="{% url 'image_list' listing.id %}">View Listing and Images</a>`. You can add more features on top of it.

Comment: Almost the right idea, trying to do it all through just the one view and one url, to display it all in a single html

Comment: Then it's easy! Just in your HTML file, add `{% for listing in object_list %}`, 

`{{ listing.title }}`, and then `{% for image in listing.images.all %}`, `{{ image }}`. This should do the trick! You can use `def get_context_data(self)`inside your **views.py** to define `object_list`.

Comment: The result I am getting is for example "Listing Object (86)" for {{ image }} -- when I inspect the data in Pycharm it seems to know everything about it, file location ect, but  no idea what to do to turn that image tag into the src location to display the image, when i type {{ image.  no suggestions come up either. 
Is the information from listings.objects.all enough to get the images or will I need a listingimages.objects.all in the query as well? 
Thanks you so much, almost there! lol

Comment: Oh! I forgot about the `<img>` tag. Your images are saved somewhere. Suppose your images are stored in the static folder of your root project directory (`root/static/images/`). Then each image is getting a unique name (maybe `<id>.jpg`). Then include the relative URL as the src value inside `<img>` tag. First, try with hardcoded values. Then try to access them via the Django way (`<img src="../../static/images/{{ image.id }}.jpg">`. Try yourself several times (since I don't know your file structure and your **views.py**). You will succeed.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was what finally worked, with your suggestions and help! Greatly appreciated for your continued help!
src="{{ image.image.url }}"

Comment: I am glad it finally worked for you! I also request you to add edits to the answer to make the appropriate changes, how it worked for you. Because everyone will not go through the comments, and if someone faces the same issue as you, then the answer will help him/her.