# How to upload multiple files in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following two models.

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class EventPhotos(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='events/')
```

What I am trying to do is to use the default admin panel to select multiple images for upload.

My current code works as I want it to, I create an event then open the EventPhotos model, select the event I just created and I have the select file button which I can use to add photos, but the thing is, Django lets me add only 1 photo! I want to add multiple photos.

Thanks in advance guys, would appreciate it if you help me out.

Comment: Please add your `admin.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `admin.py` file should be like:

```py
class EventPhotosInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EventPhotos

@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EventPhotosInline,]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understand you are looking for a way to implement many to one relationship. A similar question has been answered here before, you can have a look at [Multiple images per Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model)